# if condition does not return true

Tags: python

```
string_list = ['[pool]\n', 'pool_name\n', 'node_name ip_address port\n', 'node_name ip_address port\n', 'node_name ip_address port\n', '[/pool]\n', '[pool]\n', 'pool_name\n', 'node_name ip_address port\n', 'node_name ip_address port\n', 'node_name ip_address port\n', '[/pool]\n']
for i in range(len(string_list)):
    print string_list[i]
    if string_list[i] == 'pool_name':
        print "here"
```

What I am missing in this code. The if condition does not return true.

Comment: When using both the index and the value of the element at an index, using `enumerate` is highly recommended! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
if string_list[i].strip() == 'pool_name':
```

Because

```
>>>>"pool_name\n".strip() # this will strip out \n, \r, \t, " ",
"pool_name"
```

OR

```
if string_list[i] == 'pool_name\n':
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `\n` in your statement

All your strings in the list have a `\n` at the end

```
for i in range(len(string_list)):
    print string_list[i]
    if string_list[i] == 'pool_name\n':   #Missing here
        print "here"
```

Output after changing the statement

```
[pool]

pool_name

node_name ip_address port

node_name ip_address port

node_name ip_address port

[/pool]

[pool]

pool_name

node_name ip_address port

node_name ip_address port

node_name ip_address port

[/pool]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your list the value is `'pool_name\n'`, not `'pool_name'` (difference of a `\n` char, a newline). Either do:

```
if string_list[i] == 'pool_name\n':
```

Or:

```
if string_list[i].strip() == 'pool_name':
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in string_list:
    if i.strip() == 'pool_name':
        print "here"
```

would be a more pythonic way to do it.

Or maybe just

```
if 'pool_name\n' in string_list:
    print "here"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your strings end in `'\n'`, which you are not checking for:

```
for i in range(len(string_list)):
    print string_list[i]
    if string_list[i] == 'pool_name\n':
        print "here"
```

Or, `strip` the string to remove the `'\n'`, and proceed in checking how you were:

```
for i in range(len(string_list)):
    print string_list[i]
    if string_list[i].strip() == 'pool_name':
        print "here"
```

As such:

```
>>> foo()
[pool]

pool_name

here
node_name ip_address port

node_name ip_address port

node_name ip_address port

[/pool]

[pool]

pool_name

here
node_name ip_address port

node_name ip_address port

node_name ip_address port

[/pool]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean your input by using the `strip()` function

```
string_list = ['[pool]\n', 'pool_name\n', 'node_name ip_address port\n', 'node_name ip_address port\n', 'node_name ip_address port\n', '[/pool]\n', '[pool]\n', 'pool_name\n', 'node_name ip_address port\n', 'node_name ip_address port\n', 'node_name ip_address port\n', '[/pool]\n']

string_list =   [i.strip() for i in string_list]

string_list
['[pool]', 'pool_name', 'node_name ip_address port', 'node_name ip_address port', 'node_name ip_address port', '[/pool]', '[pool]', 'pool_name', 'node_name ip_address port', 'node_name ip_address port', 'node_name ip_address port', '[/pool]']
```

then you can do what you are doing

```
for i in range(len(string_list)):
    print string_list[i]
    if string_list[i] == 'pool_name':   
        print "here"
```